VS2022 Can't set File or Assembly Version in DLL
In this previous question of mine, I thought I had worked out setting version information in a VS2022 C# project.  But I seem to have run into the issue again and can't figure it out.  The main difference between then and now is that in that previous question I was working on an application, while today I'm working on a DLL.
I have these settings explicitly set in my VS2022 project


And this is reflected in the details in the csproj file:
 <PropertyGroup>
   <GeneratePackageOnBuild>True</GeneratePackageOnBuild>
   <Title>blah blah</Title>
   <PackageReadmeFile>readme.md</PackageReadmeFile>
   <Version>1.0.2</Version>
   <FileVersion>1.0.2</FileVersion>
   <AssemblyVersion>1.0.2</AssemblyVersion>
   <Authors>blah blah</Authors>
   <Description>blah blah blah, blah blah</Description>
   <Copyright>Copyright blah blah 2024</Copyright>
 </PropertyGroup>

But after building, when I look at the DLL properties via File Explorer I see this:

And for comparison, I tried this powershell command to inspect the DLL, which confirmed the Explorer's results:

In addition I also set the copyright information in the project, and that is also blank in the DLL's properties.
So what's going on here?  How come I can't set either the file or assembly version?
The reason that this is important to me is that I am producing a NuGet package during the build, and it seems the package thinks the DLL is 1.02, but the DLL is not 1.02, and when the NuGet package DLL is loaded into another application, the application falls over as it can't find the expected DLL version.
FWIW this DLL project was upgraded from VS2017 to a VS2022 project.  So the automatic upgrade may have missed something.  However, today is the first day that I actually tried setting the DLL's version properties after leaving them as the default since the start of the project.

Try checking AssemblyInfo.cs: If your project was upgraded from an older Visual Studio version (eg.VS2017-VS2022), there may be AssemblyInfo.cs (a file containing assembly properties), and the properties in it may override the settings in the .csproj file.

@DennisLi There is no AssemblyInfo.cs file in that project.  Although I didn't mention it in my question, I went looking for it before posting.  However, your question did prompt me to look at the stuff and I've found the solution.

Great to hear that. Congratulations!

After being prompted by @DennisLi's question about AssemblyInfo.cs, I went looking at that and other things in the project.
First of all, this project doesn't have a AssemblyInfo.cs file.  However, when looking at the details of the csproj file I saw this:
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0-windows8.0</TargetFramework>
    <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
    <GenerateAssemblyInfo>false</GenerateAssemblyInfo>
    <UseWPF>true</UseWPF>
    <ImportWindowsDesktopTargets>true</ImportWindowsDesktopTargets>
  </PropertyGroup>

The key point being the GenerateAssemblyInfo element.  This is apparently meant to control the generation of assembly etc information from either the  old style AssemblyInfo.cs file and the new style SDK project files.
When it is false, the information is meant to come from the AssemblyInfo.cs file.  But as noted, this file is not in the current project.  However, the file did exist in the original VS2017 project before I updated to the VS2022 project.
As as test I commented out that element like so:
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0-windows8.0</TargetFramework>
    <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
    <!--<GenerateAssemblyInfo>false</GenerateAssemblyInfo>-->
    <UseWPF>true</UseWPF>
    <ImportWindowsDesktopTargets>true</ImportWindowsDesktopTargets>
  </PropertyGroup>

This resulted in the expected information turning up in the file properties:

It looks like that something went wrong during the conversion from the old to new projects, and I was left in limbo with the version information expected to be in the AssemblyInfo.cs file, but the conversion had deleted that file.
